# Add user to ManyToManyField

Tags: django, database, django-models

I'm failing to add user into a ManyToManyField. Using Django 1.11. Following this documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.set

My template:

```
<ul>
    {% for a in stories %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'story:add_story' a.id %}">{{ a }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

My view:

```
def add_story(request, park_id):

    story = get_object_or_404(Story, pk=story_id)    
    story.users.add(request.user)

    stories = Story.objects.filter(users=request.user)

    context = {
        'stories': stories,
    }
    return render(request, 'story/manage.html', context)
```

My model:

```
class Story(models.Model):
    story_name = models.CharField(max_length=550)    
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='subscriber')
    dateAdded = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    userAdded = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I can't figure out where I'm going wrong. The user is not added and I get no errors at all.

Comment: You haven't said what is wrong.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Sorry. I'll update the question. Well nothing happens. The user is not added and no errors.

Comment: Are you sure the view is getting called? Can you put some logging into that view?

Comment: show your `views` which call the template, simple you can show full views code, and `urls`

Comment: @sumpen check my updated answer

Comment: @DanielRoseman You got me on right track. I changed the return statement to return HttpResspone to see that it triggered. The fault where in urls. I decalred path as manage/add_story. But did not need the 'manage/'. Thanks!